# partial classes + DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a class that was generated for me by the Entity Framework:

**Models/EF.tt/Product.cs**

```
public partial class X
{
  public int Name { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

I don't want to modify it because it's managed by the EF editor and it will wipe out my modifications any time I regenerate it, so I'm putting code into a separate file.  Because the classes are declared as *partial* I can do useful things... what I haven't been able to figure out is how to use DataAnnotations for the properties.

**Models/EF.custom.cs**

```
public partial class X
{
  [Display(Name = "My Name")]
  public int Name { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

which fails... what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your going to want to use a metadatatype:

http://ryanhayes.net/blog/data-annotations-for-entity-framework-4-entities-as-an-mvc-model/

Comment: awesome.  thanks @klabranche! I would never have figured out how to google for such a thing.